# Set up Firebase and the Dynamic Links SDK IOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I've followed the steps described in Firebase Dynamic Links doc for setting up dynamic links for iOS, but when I check

```
https://my_app_code.app.goo.gl/apple-app-site-association
```

the `details` node is always empty.

Did anyone had this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe It is a little bit late for you but for those with the same problem, it takes some minutes since you introduce all the fields in Dynamic Links Setup.